# AJAX Actualizar datos en vivo

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Estoy escribiendo un sistema que debe actualizar dos divs, en lo posible, en tiempo real. 
La forma que encontré de hacerlo es la siguiente, mediante AJAX:

```js
function actualizarDatos(){
 
 $.ajax({
  
  type: 'POST',
  cache: false,
  async:true,
  url: 'lista_datos1.php',
  success: function(respuesta) {
   
  $('#ListaDatos1').html(respuesta);
    }
 });


 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  cache: false,
    async:true,
  url: 'lista_datos2.php',
  success: function(respuesta) {
   
  $('#ListaDatos2').html(respuesta);
    }
 });
 
}

setInterval( function(){
    
 actualizarDatos();
 
},3000)//Actualizo cada 3 segundos
```

Ya he notado algunas inconsistencias al utilizarlo y esta aplicación web será ejecutada por varios usuarios simultáneos.

¿Es correcto lo que estoy haciendo? 
¿Sugieren una mejor manera de hacerlo?

Agradezco sus comentarios, saludos!

Comment: tu codigo esta bien sin envargo es inefisiente y consume demasiado recursos , te recomiendo aprender sobre websockects para actualizaciones en tiempo real, en ves de tu estar pidiendo actualizaciones a cada 3 segundos los sockets te mandan los nuevos cambios de tu base de datos en tiempo real sin tener que pedirlos y es aseptados por todos los navegadores ya que esta entre los protocolos del mismo ,http,https,tcp etc..

Comment: mira esta libreria https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo te recomiendo que tengas una única llamda ajax dentro de la fucnión `actualizarDatos()` y que en el código `php` te devuelves los dos datos que quieres actualizar.

```
function actualizarDatos(){

    $.ajax({

        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        async:true,
        url: 'lista_datos1.php',
        success: function(respuesta) {
          //Suponiendo que devuelves en un array los datos
          $('#ListaDatos1').html(respuesta[0]);
          $('#ListaDatos2').html(respuesta[1]);
       }
    });

}

setInterval( function(){

    actualizarDatos();

},3000)//Actualizo cada 3 segundos
```

Dependiendo de la forma que quieras regresar los datos de tu `php` podrías adecuar la función `success`.